# statsmodels glm fit_constrained 'unrecognized token'

Tags: python, statsmodels

Trying to use statsmodels.glm with constraints and unable to get (what I think should be) a simple requirement to work...

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.tools import add_constant
from statsmodels.formula.api import glm

test = np.array([[10,29,30],[32,26,23],[34,39,46]])
exog = add_constant(test)
y = np.array([11,23,27])

formula = 'y ~ x + q'
formula_df = formula_df = pd.DataFrame({'y' : y,'x':test[:,0],'q':test[:,1],'r':test[:,2],'int':exog[:,3]})

glmm = glm(formula=formula,data=formula_df)

glmm_results = glmm.fit_constrained(constraints='q = 0')
print(glmm_results.summary())
```

from the docs for fit constraints:

```
The constraints are of the form R params = q where R is the constraint_matrix and q is the vector of constraint_values.

The estimation creates a new model with transformed design matrix, exog, and converts the results back to the original parameterization.

Parameters

    constraintsformula expression or tuple

        If it is a tuple, then the constraint needs to be given by two arrays (constraint_matrix, constraint_value), i.e. (R, q). Otherwise, the constraints can be given as strings or list of strings. see t_test for details
```

however, if I try to simply ensure that q is > 0 by changing the constraint to:

```
glm_results = glmm.fit_constrained(constraints='q > 0')
```

then i get an unrecognized token error

```
PatsyError: unrecognized token in constraint
    q > 0
      ^
```

I've tried '>>' as well. There isn't much documentation I can find for statsmodels and writing constraints beyond what I copy/pasted above.  How do I get this to work?

An alternate question would be how do I write the 4 simplest types of constraints on coefficients in the q,R format (x = 0, x<0, x>0, a<x<b)?

Comment: `fit_constrained` only handles linear equality constraints, not inequality constraints.

Comment: sad...glm does everything else I want out of a model (provides errors on coefficients, allows symbolic formula descriptions and equality constraints). are there any python solvers that can do all that out of the box along with inequality constraints?

Comment: Not for GLMs. Inequality constraints are theoretically more challenging and equality constraints since inference depends on whether the constraints are binding or not. In the case of equality constraints, they are always binding and so the restricted model is just an affine transformation of a smaller but unrestricted model, and so inference can be directly made with the smaller unrestricted model.